# Use hibernate model to deliver data into other class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, type-conversion

Have problem with converting object into collection class(entity class).

Have 2 tables, with ManyToOne

Computer class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "pc_key")
public PcKeys getPcKeys() {
    return this.pcKeys;
}
```

PcKeys class

```
@Column(name = "pc_key", unique = true, length = 32)
public String getPcKey() {
    return this.pcKey;
}
```

Sample query:

```
"select c.id, pk.pcKey from Computers c, PcKeys pk
```

After transaction I got data in object and try to convert it into model:

```
Computers.setPcKeys((PcKeys) object[1]);
```

But deliverd data is only a String.

Any ones know how to convert that properly? Or mybe i need to build new collection for that?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand just what you are asking here.

Comment: Sorry:) I want to use same model class(entity class) to send data forward. But hibernate entity class have foreign key, with one change my pc Key String(foreign key) into PcKeys Enitity class(whithone have this key). Now: when i make a statement i recive String with this key, but entity class have a collection init. How to use the collection(Computers) with the foreign key. Really dont know how to explaint that better

Comment: You can do this by using DTO and `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`

Comment: Or after transaction you are getting data in List<object>. you can loop over it after that create new object of `Computer` set `object[0]` into id of `computer` after that create new object of `PcKeys` set `object[1]` into pcKey (PcKeys.setPcKey(object[1])). set pcKey object into `computer` object and then add `computer` object into an list of Computer.